# ko jquery autocomplete custom binding overrides previous binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, knockout.js, autocomplete

I've written a simple custom binding for jquery autocomplete as shown here:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.autoComplete = {
init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
    var self = this;
    self.getUrl= ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
    self.successCallBack = allBindingsAccessor().successCallBack;
    self.selectCallBack = allBindingsAccessor().selectCallBack;

    $(element).autocomplete({
        minLength: 3,
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: self.getUrl + request.term,
                type: 'GET',
                cache: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    response(self.successCallBack(data));
                },
            });
        },
        error: function(xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('some error occured', textStatus, errorThrown);
        },
        open: function () {
            $(element).data("uiAutocomplete").menu.element.addClass("dropdown-menu-xs");
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            self.selectCallBack(event, ui);
        }
    });
}
};
```

It works fine when I have just one element in my page that has this binding, but when I have 2 or more elements, the url of the latest autocomplete field gets applied to ALL the elements with the autoComplete binding

For example if I have on my page:

```
<input id="first" type="text" class="form-control input-xs" data-bind="autoComplete: firstURL" />

<input id="second" type="text" class="form-control input-xs" data-bind="autoComplete: secondURL" />
```

Both input elements will end up with 'secondURL' in their respective ajax calls.

I've tried logging both the 'element' and 'getUrl' values in the console and they display as different.

Would really appreciate any insight on what I'm doing wrong, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `this`. The `init` function is not a constructor. You can make a `self` that is an object literal, or just use `var`s for your callbacks.